# Where to put constants and types React Typescript

Tags: reactjs

I am curious to know where on should put constants and types that are used in many parts of the app. What is the best practice to organize this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting files and and making good structure of is an art and very crucial for large scale application.
For the best practice our code should not have any constants inside our component we should decide a common place to put all of our constants and type. So that we make less mistakes and follow the dry(don't repeat yourself) principle.

we should keep our constant and type like this...

put all of your types inside modules folder with this navigation

***src/store/modules/app.types.ts***

and put you constants in utils folder with this navigation

***src/utils/validation.constant.ts***

Again it depends how you are structuring your project.
Happy Learning

Comment: Do you know of any CRA github repos with good file structure (gold standard)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, I don't know any github repo, there is tons of articles on internet about good structure just go and follow one

Comment: Sorry if this comes off lazy, but there are so many that I don't know which to follow. Do you think you could suggest one? Thanks

Comment: @NickSmith Here is [template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-template-rich) I like to use for my react applications. It may help you in taking few decisions about your application.